# Set custom address attribute value programmatically

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-address, eav-attributes

I'm using `Magento v2.1.6` and I have created a **`custom attribute`** for **`customer address`** like this:

```
$customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer_address');
$attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

$attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
$attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

$customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'subdistrict', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'District',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'sort_order' => 83,
                'position' => 83,
                'system' => 0,
]);

$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'subdistrict')
                ->addData([
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address','customer_address']
                ]);
$attribute->save();
```

I tried to save/update in one of the customer address like this:

```
public function __construct( 
  \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
)
{ 
   $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
}

public function execute(){
 $addressId = 1;
 $subdistrict = "Harbor City";
 $address = $this->addressRepository->getById($addressId);
 $address->setCustomAttribute('subdistrict',$subdistrict); 
 $this->addressRepository->save($address);
}
```

But I am always getting an error saying :

> {"0":"Class object does not exist","1":"#0
>   /var/www/Project/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php(155):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('object')\n#1
>   /var/www/Project/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php(106)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass **\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address** object for save customer address attribute value.

```
<?php
public function __construct(        
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,      
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory
)
{ 
   $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
   $this->addressDataFactory = $addressDataFactory;
   parent::__construct($context);
}

protected function _extractAddress()
{
    $customerId = YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID; //5

    $addressDataObject = $this->addressDataFactory->create();        
    $addressDataObject->setCustomerId($customerId)
         ->setCustomAttribute('subdistrict',$subdistrict)
         ->setIsDefaultBilling(1)
         ->setIsDefaultShipping(1);
    return $addressDataObject;
}
/**
  * Save customer address attribute value
  */
public function execute()
{
    try {
        $address = $this->_extractAddress();
        $this->_addressRepository->save($address);
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: This does not work because of missing required fields

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, I have created multi-select attribute successfully, value not getting saved from admin. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260079/multiselect-attribute-not-saving-in-magento-2-3-0

Comment: ->setCustomAttribute('subdistrict',$subdistrict)
works

Answer (score 1):

For show it on address/edit.phtml like :

```
<?=$block->getAddress()->getShippingInfo();?>
```

Add in your di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address" type="vendor\CustomerAccount\Model\Data\Address" />
```

And in your model :

```
<?php


namespace vendor\CustomerAccount\Model\Data;

class Address extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address
{
    /**
     * Get shipping_info
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getShippingInfo()
    {
        return $this->_get('shipping_info');
    }
}
```

The save is automatic if you have created it normaly

Answer (score -1):

You need to used code like this.

```
protected $customerFactory;
protected $customerData;
protected $customer;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer $customerData)
    {
        $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->customerData = $customerData;
    }

public function execute()
{
   $customerId = YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID;
   $subdistrict = "Downtown";
   $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
   $this->customerData = $this->customer->getDataModel();
   $this->customerData->setId($customerId);
   $this->customerData->setCustomAttribute('subdistrict', $subdistrict);
   $this->customer->updateData($this->customerData);
}
```

Comment: @DhirenVason its for customer address attribute not customer attribute

Comment: @IdhamChoudry can you tell, in your above code, for what you have create attribute?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, Here i am facing same issue, can you look inti it please, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260079/multiselect-attribute-not-saving-in-magento-2-3-0